# How to get a config parameter in package in config specific bundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-4.3

I've create my bundle so i want to get some config value

```
imk_form:
  form_template: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates/forms'
```

I want to get `form_template` in my service or in my class

```
imk_form:
  form_template: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates/forms'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it seems that we can't retrieve nested parameters values from the config file, even if Symfony doesn't throw any error when you define them this way. You will have to use a fully qualified parameter name instead.

**config.yml**

```
parameters:
    imk_form.form_template: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates/forms'
```

**services.yml**

```
AppBundle\Service\YourService:
    arguments:
        $form_template: '%imk_form.form_template%'
```

**YourService.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

class YourService {
  private $form_template;

  public function __construct($form_template)
  {
    $this->form_template = $form_template;
  }
}
```